# How to detect clicked element added dynamic using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

How can I detect clicked element in code like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
  <a href=""><b>Foo</b></a>
</div>   
<div class="bar">
  <a href=""><b>Bar</b></a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.foo, .bar', function (e) {     
   if (detectElement == '.bar') {
     //
   }
}
```

I try `$('this')` but returned `body` not clicked element.
I try also `e.target` but I want get main element (`.foo` or `.bar`), not `<a>` / `<b>`

Comment: what do you mean by added dynamic? added using jquery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('this')` isn't right. `this` is variable that contain clicked element. You can't use it as string. Use [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check element has specific class name.

```
$('body').on('click', '.foo, .bar', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('bar')) {
        // code
    }
});
```

```js
$('body').on('click', '.foo, .bar', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('bar'))
        console.log("is .bar");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <a href="#"><b>Foo</b></a>
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <a href="#"><b>Bar</b></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

> Check the current matched set of elements against a `selector`, element, or jQuery object and return `true` if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

and The selector is not correct instead use [`event.currentTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/), , when you use `$('this')` is [Element Selector (“element”)](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) since you have no HTML element as `this` the condition does't works.

> The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.

```
$('body').on('click', '.foo, .bar', function (event) {
    if ($(event.currentTarget).is('.bar')) {
        //Your code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `currentTarget` attribute of the `event` callback.

```
$('body').on('click', '.foo, .bar', function (e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).hasClass('foo') {
    alert('Foo has been clicked');
  }

  $(e.currentTarget).hasClass('bar') {
    alert('Bar has been clicked');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!